# Image does not display even though I have the right file path

Tags: css

So to keep it short: I am trying to implement an image, but the image keeps on throwing in the error `GET http://localhost/keuzedeel/images/naturebg.jpg 404 (Not Found)` and then displays nothing...
 Even though (according to me) I have the right file path.

- I have a CSS folder with a css file in it
- I have a js folder (what won't be very useful in resolving this, but just mentioning in case)
- I have an images folder
- I have the root folder named "keuzedeel"

this is how my HTML header looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainpage.css">
```

This is how I try to create the background image in my css file: `background-image: url('/keuzedeel/images/naturebg.jpg');`

Yes, the extension is a `.jpg`.

I have looked into a couple of StackOverflow questions, but none of them have helped. Could it maybe be a 403? (access denied)

Comment: if the root folder is keuzedeel then the url could be http://localhost/images/naturebg.jpg

Comment: Already tried that (aswell), but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Try this `background-image: url('../images/naturebg.jpg');`

Comment: The server responded with the same error...

Comment: It could be your server configuration. What server are you using?

Comment: I am using XAMPP (apache). I too personally think it could be the server config. could you post what you think it is? maybe that's the problem?